# Kotlin Android app crashes when moving to new activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This should be simple but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
I want my code to go from one activity to another when a button is clicked.

The current activity is called MainActivity and the activity it redirects to is called 'KickTrend'

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val trend_btn : Button = findViewById(R.id.viewTrend)
        trend_btn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,KickTrend::class.java)
            Toast.makeText(this, "moving to new Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

The toast is showing up but the then the app crashes at `startActivity(intent)` line
The Kick Trend activity kotlin file looks like this:

```
class KickTrend : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kick_trend)
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong. I am coming back to Android development after almost 6-7 years and alot has changed so maybe I am missing some syntax or library..I dunno.

The Manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TrackMyBaby"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TrackMyBaby">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".KickTrend"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The log cat is as follows:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.trackmybaby, PID: 19231
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.trackmybaby/com.example.trackmybaby.KickTrend}:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
> theme (or descendant) with this activity.
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4111)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4277)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a
> Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:926)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:889)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:772)
> at
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
> at com.example.trackmybaby.KickTrend.onCreate(KickTrend.kt:9)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8270)
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4085)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4277) 
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)

Comment: Can you post the logcat log? Have you declared the activity in the manifest file?

Comment: What does the log say? Usually, this happens when the new activity isn't defined in your manifest. Can you upload your manifest as well?

Comment: I think it is because in the first activity I am extending the class ComponentActivity and in the latter I am using AppCompatActivity. Can anyone explain why? Sofar I know AppCompatActivity is a descendant of ComponentActivity right?

Comment: @AmritaDeb https://stackoverflow.com/q/21814825/6059583 you can follow this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're encountering indicates that the theme you've set for your `KickTrend` activity is not compatible with the AppCompat theme requirements. The `AppCompatActivity` class (which KickTrend extends) requires that the theme used in the activity is a descendant of `Theme.AppCompat`. I suppose you can do following things to fix the issue:

1. Extend your MainActivity from `AppCompatActivity`, not the `ComponentActivity`
2. Make sure that your `Theme.TrackMyBaby` is extended from AppCompat theme, not the regular one. You cannot use non-appcompat themes for `AppCompatActivity`. Like this

   ```
    <resources>
    <style name="Theme.TrackMyBaby" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- ... theme attributes ... -->
    </style>
   ```
3. Just in case you can define a theme in `AndroidManifest.xml` for your `KickTrend` activity.

   ```
    <!-- AndroidManifest.xml -->
    <activity
        android:name=".KickTrend"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </activity>
   ```